# Initial state for QAOA

Tags: optimization, qaoa

I'm learning about QAOA and I got curious about how they choose initial state. They somehow decided to choose initial state as equal superposition of all possible state and I wonder that there is any particular reason for that.

- Initial state from https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab/files/qiskit-textbook/content/ch-applications/qaoa.ipynb

In 5.3 quantum circuit
" We first implement 5 Hadamard H gates to generate the uniform superposition. "

Comment: regarding the last sentence: no, an equal superposition of the basis states for multiple qubits is not an entangled state of those qubits, it is the tensor product of equal superpositions on the individual qubits. I think you should remove that and only ask about the reasoning behind the initial state...

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i edited it. I got too curious and mixed up my questions, sorry. Last sentence was : equal superposition of all possible state = maximally entangled state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that state $H^{\otimes n} |0\rangle^ {\otimes n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_{i=0}^{2^n-1}|i\rangle$, where $|i\rangle$ being a binary representation of decimal number $i$, is a ground state of Hamiltonian
$$
\mathcal{H}_0 =\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \sigma_i ^x,
$$
where $\sigma_i ^x$ is $X$ gate applied on $i$th qubit whereas identity gate is applied on other qubits.

The Hamiltonian $H_0$ is used as an initial Hamiltonian for Ising model.

You can find more about this in [my other answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/18507/standard-to-select-base-hamiltonaian-for-adiabatic-quantum-computing/18509#18509).

Comment: So did they just used ground state in the beginning? Shouldn't we supposed to find a ground state using variational method? I thought hamiltonian is fixed and we find ground state, but in your answer, it seems we already know the ground state and we are finding hamiltonian. Did i understand variational method wrong?

Comment: @hongildong1:  In fact, QAOA simulates a quantum annealer. The annealer is in a ground state all time. At the beginning in ground state of a known Hamiltonian, at the end in ground state of Hamiltonian whose ground state your are looking for. See the linked answer for more detailed explanation of quantum annealing.

Comment: So QAOA uses adabatic theorem, but VQE or other variational algorithms don't use adiabatic theorem? In Variational quantum algorithms, is my understanding of variational method okay?

Comment: @hongildong1: Yes, you are right. QAOA is actually simulation of a quantum annealer. VQE circuit is based on something another. However, the question was about QAOA :-)

Comment: I'm so confusing... i heard that QAOA is sub-VQE. Your comment salvaged me.

Answer (score 1):

A maximally entangled state is a state that has maximum mutual information of
the random variables. I think you should first clear your concept about entanglement. [http://www.cmi.ac.in/~neelraha/Resources/Internships/MayJuly2016/Maximally_Entangled_States.pdf](http://www.cmi.ac.in/%7Eneelraha/Resources/Internships/MayJuly2016/Maximally_Entangled_States.pdf)

Comment: I would suggest to post this as an comment.

Comment: My answer was to the previous question. @hongildong1 if you have a new question do ask it separately next time.

Comment: I had a look at the original question and now I understand. No problem then.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Your answer helped me a lot. Thank you